# Is there a way to run a task when a process has completed its operation?

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler, task-scheduler, scheduling

I am an expert in writing .bat files, I am experienced in writing .ps1 files, I just learned to use `taskschd` to create scheduled tasks.

Currently I can set a time to trigger a script, I know I can define triggers as on user logon, on system boot etc., it is easy, but I am wondering if there is a way to define triggers as on completion of a given process, either in `taskschd` or in PowerShell.

For example, run a hash check with PowerShell when a file download has been completed by a downloader, or compare two folders in cmd when explorer has finished copying a folder, or install Windows to a drive using `dism` in cmd when a separate cmd has completed formatting that drive...

Is there any way to achieve this? Do I need to create the task while the process is running so I can use its PID, or I can use its path and/or name as well? In the above scenarios after the operations has been completed the processes are waiting for further instructions, not doing any more operations, have become idle, not using CPU, maybe this can help defining the trigger...

Comment: A simple bat file where you put the second task after the first one, is probably too easy?

Comment: Say if I want to download a file, and then check hash, do I have to use cli to download files? What would happen if I run a download command then run Get-Filehash? Plus downloaders do multithread downloading.

Comment: Being a Linux user myself, I'm not used to running tasks with a GUI.  Using a quiet wget for downloads, eg.

Comment: I am with @GerardH.Pille.  This is all silly.  Just run them sequentially.  Why make it so complicated?  I myself would do this with batch ('cause its so simple) but powershell can accomplish the same thing.  Via batch, `start /wait <thingamajigger>` on the first line.  `if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" <do the next thingy>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *For example, run a hash check with PowerShell when a file download has been completed by a downloader, or compare two folders in cmd when explorer has finished copying a folder, or install Windows to a drive using dism in cmd when a separate cmd has completed formatting that drive...*
>
> *Is there any way to achieve this?*

What I would do, and have done a lot in similar cases (in bat/cmd), would be to manipulate the system variables (setx), but reading and writing values ​​directly in the register, so, in execution instead, it is possible to send the status of executions and their results.

You can create a logic that understands you at each moment of the script execution, and obtain the status of this action when finished, or even update the information read for relevant readings and executions by another script.

In short, all actions can be taken based on values ​​read / written by one or more scripts in execution (or called execution), and it can "report" its status by updating the information read after starting/ending each action with the results, including pointing out ways to handle the logs, or even, in your case, downloading, installing, calculating hashes, etc.

Below I left a simple example, where the execution of a script changes/writes the values ​​in the registry, and the other will read those values.

---

```
$Job = {    
    if ((Get-itemproperty -Path 'HKCU:\Environment').Status_Job -eq 'Starting') {

        Write-Host "Status_Job Starting, you can execute your "
        Write-Host "command accordingly the status Starting Status_Job!" ; sleep -M 1500 ; &$Job

      } elseif ((Get-itemproperty -Path 'HKCU:\Environment').Status_Job -eq 'Running') {

        Write-Host "Status_Job Running, you can execute your "
        Write-Host "command accordingly the status Running Status_Job" ; sleep -M 1500 ; &$Job   
       
      } elseif ((Get-itemproperty -Path 'HKCU:\Environment').Status_Job -eq 'Downloading') {
        Write-Host "Status_Job Downloading, you can execute your "
        Write-Host "command accordingly the status Downloading Status_Job" ; sleep -M 1500 ; &$Job   
    
      } elseif ((Get-itemproperty -Path 'HKCU:\Environment').Status_Job -eq 'Done') {

        Write-Host "Status_Job Done, you can execute your "
        Write-Host "command accordingly the status Done Status_Job"

      }
   }

For($i = 1; $i -lt 3; $i++){sleep 1; &$Job}
```

```
if ((Get-itemproperty -Path 'HKCU:\Environment').Status_Job) {
     Remove-ItemProperty -Name Status_Job -Path 'HKCU:\Environment' }

  1..20 | ForEach-Object {

    sleep 1; if ($_ -eq 20) {

        Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Environment" -Name Status_Job -Value 'Done' -Type MultiString
        $_ ;     sleep -M 250

      } elseif ($_ -eq 15)  {

        Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Environment" -Name Status_Job -Value 'Downloading' -Type MultiString
        $_ ;     sleep -M 250

      } elseif ($_ -eq 10)  {

        Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Environment" -Name Status_Job -Value 'Running' -Type MultiString
        $_ ;    sleep -M 250

      } elseif ($_ -eq 5)  {

        Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Environment" -Name Status_Job -Value 'Running' -Type MultiString
        $_ ;    sleep -M 250

      } elseif ($_ -eq 1){

        Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Environment" -Name Status_Job -Value 'Starting' -Type MultiString
        $_ ;    sleep -M 250

      }

   }
```

---

I am not an expert in PowerShell, far from it, but I understood that your doubt is more focused on the mechanics of the process itself, than the necessary code.

---

- Some further reading:

[√] **[Create Environment Variable in Windows 10](https://winaero.com/create-environment-variable-windows-10/)**

[√] **[Set environment variable - SETX | Refer: PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48806379/set-environment-variable-setx)**

[√] **[Jumping around to certain spots in script | Refer: Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20221880/8177207)**    **[@by AdamL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1980228/adaml)**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are ways to do this all in PowerShell, no .bat/.cmd needed. Yet, note, Stack* is not a script writing service as per the rules of engagement pointed to above.

You have a project here, and it should be approached one step at a time to make sure you are getting the results you'd expect, before moving to the next step.

> Create a script which…
>
> 1. Get the hash from a file on the website
> 2. Download a file from the web
> 3. Monitor for completion
> 4. Unblock the file
> 5. Validate hash
> 6. Run the installer
> 7. Generate a report of success and failure
>
> … and, once all the above steps are validated individually, then
> create a new task, and assign the script to it for execution

PowerShell provides cmdlets to do this as well as it being well documented all over the web and [Youtube videos](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=beginning%20powershell) as well as in the PowerShell help files. Use the following to pull something together, and get back to us if/when you have issues.

```
# Get specifics for a module, cmdlet, or function
(Get-Command -Name Get-Help).Parameters
(Get-Command -Name Get-Help).Parameters.Keys
Get-help -Name Get-Help -Examples
Get-help -Name Get-Help -Full
Get-help -Name Get-Help -Online
    
(Get-Command -Name Get-FileHash).Parameters
(Get-Command -Name Get-FileHash).Parameters.Keys
Get-help -Name Get-FileHash -Examples
Get-help -Name Get-FileHash -Full
Get-help -Name Get-FileHash -Online

(Get-Command -Name Get-Process).Parameters
(Get-Command -Name Get-Process).Parameters.Keys
Get-help -Name Get-Process -Examples
Get-help -Name Get-Process -Full
Get-help -Name Get-Process -Online
    
(Get-Command -Name Compare-Object).Parameters
(Get-Command -Name Compare-Object).Parameters.Keys
Get-help -Name Compare-Object -Examples
Get-help -Name Compare-Object -Full
Get-help -Name Compare-Object -Online

Get-Command -Name '*transfer*', '*webrequest*', '*restmethod*', '*unblock*', '*task*', '*performance*'
```

['PowerShell ways to download a file'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27PowerShell%20ways%20to%20download%20a%20file%27&t=h_&ia=web)

['PowerShell about workflow'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27PowerShell%20about%20workflow%27&t=h_&ia=web)

['PowerShell about jobs'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27PowerShell%20about%20jobs%27&t=h_&ia=web)